# Managing Android Marketplace publishing Google Apps

Tags: google-apps, android

I am a Google Apps administrator for our organization. One of our staff has developed an App that they wish to publish to the Android marketplace.  I would like to enable the Android Market Publisher Site in Google Services but I cannot tell whether there are features for managing which Apps get published by one of our users.

Is there an approval process for Google Apps Administrators when a user wants to publish an App?

Comment: Yours appears to be more a developer question than a power user

Comment: I don't need help writing apps, just managing the approval process in Google Apps.   I think it's a Sysadmin question but since it's Google Apps and not hardware I didn't think it would fit in ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do anything, or actually have any control over the process.

You should just go here (https://market.android.com/publish/signup) and tell your developer to follow these steps:

1. Create a developer profile
2. Pay a registration fee ( $25.00) with your credit card (using Google Checkout)
3. Agree to the Android Market Developer Distribution Agreement

You can get an app up in less than 10 minutes on Google App Marketplace